# Python delete file, invalid path

Tags: python

I want to delete a file located on my desktop:

```
os.remove('C:/Benutzer/Me/Desktop/sync.txt')
```

But I get

```
[Error 3] System cannot find the path
```

However the file does exist in the given location. I can copy the path and paste into explorer. This will open the file.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure, that the '/' are correct? Remember, that on windows you need to use '\'.

Comment: Error 3 is path not found rather than file not found. Something's up with the path.

Comment: try `os.path.exists('C:/Benutzer/Me/Desktop/sync.txt')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are on Vista or 7? Then be aware of the UI to do quite a lot of localization.

Probably the path is really `C:\Users\...`, with the localization to `Benutzer` happening in the UI.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer.  I googled and found this: [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Where-are-my-files-and-folders-after-upgrading-from-Windows-XP-or-Windows-Vista)

Answer (score 3):

Try using backslashes instead of slashes, i.e. `'C:\Benutzer\Me\Desktop\sync.txt'` (dos/windows style paths). To avoid the backslashes from being treated as escaping character use a raw string:

```
os.remove(r'C:\Benutzer\Me\Desktop\sync.txt')
```

Comment: This won't be it since a `/` is a perfectly valid path separator on windows.

Comment: isn't `/` is platform independent??

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the directory path is correct, if slashes causing problem (dont have to be) try this:

```
import os
filePath = 'C:' + os.path.sep + 'Benutzer' + os.path.sep + 'Me' + os.path.sep + 'Desktop' + os.path.sep + 'sync.txt'
os.remove(filePath)
```

the advantage of using `os.path.sep` here is that now you dont have to worry whether you are on `linux` or `windows` or whatever...

Comment: Your are principially right, but this solution looks ugly. A semantically equivalent, but better solution is `filePath = os.path.join('C:', 'Benutzer', 'Me', 'Desktop', 'sync.txt')`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the correct answer.  I googled and found this: [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Where-are-my-files-and-folders-after-upgrading-from-Windows-XP-or-Windows-Vista)

Folder name (and path) in Windows XP
Documents and Settings (C:\Documents and Settings)

In Vista and 7 it is moved to c:\Users